# How can I contact server admins in Battlefield Bad Company 2?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

When a server has clearly posted rules and someone's violating them, I point out the offender's sad counter-social behavior by chat—politely, twice.

If the behavior continues (it always continues) I get the irresistible urge to tattle, hoping somebody will kick the putz.

What's the best way to contact admins? General chat? I've read that some servers (BC2CC?) support chat-based directives like !admins and !calladmin, but I've never gotten them to work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Can I tell whether I'm on a server that supports them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Far as I know, BC2 doesn't support this by default. You have to find a well-administered server. 
On "big name" servers, the keywords I've had the most luck with have been "admin" and "reporting". 
Keep in mind that a server admin can see *all* chat, so it might be best to type to your squad instead of general chat. Typing in general chat is an incite for flamewar, and it's more trouble than it's worth.

Personally speaking, I'd much rather see a squad chat report because the person reporting this is more interested in fixing the problem than starting some kind of a "he-said/she-said" flamewar in general chat.

Comment: That works for me. Thanks for the tip about using squad chat.